# Storing and displaying rich text efficiently

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, richtextbox

I need to store significant amounts of rich text in a SQL database, retrieve it and display it.

One font throughout is OK but I need different font sizes/bold/colors.

For now I am using a RichTextBox (WPF) to display it, and XamlWriter.Save/XamlReader.Parse to serialize it to strings to store in the DB. It works well but the RichTextBox is so HUGELY SLOW at displaying the text that it's basically unusable.

Is there a quick way to do this with acceptable performance?

I'm considering doing it with GlyphRun objects, drawing each character as a bitmap and computing all the alignment requirements to fit the destination image etc... But reinventing the wheel on simple colored/sizable text seems really strange in 2011.

**EDIT**:
Thanks for the answers, didn't see them until now, sorry.

Text is entered by the user from `RichTextBox`es as well, basically I just save the resulting `string` `XamlWriter.Save(richTextBox.Document)` in the database. Other fields (double/int etc) are also entered by the user from `TextBox`es.

As the user queries the database, pages of read-only rich text with colors and formatting is generated from scratch using the fields in the database, including the saved rich text fields above: these are converted from `FlowDocument`s to `Span`s and some replacement is done on them (`InlineUIContainer`s which host a class derived from `UIElement` which references a database entry, inlined in the text, like "see [thisbook]" where [thisbook] references some database entry's ID). MSDN says all that is far too much text for a `TextBlock`.

That text rendering is the really slow part but there is no way around it, I need that formatting and it's just how the WPF `RichTextBox`es are: even when entering a little simple text in the `RichTextBox`es, there is a delay between typing and the character appearing on the screen...

For now I still use `RichTextBox`es but I keep lots of rendered layouts in memory (the `Paragraph`/`Section`/`Span` objects) and I am careful to rerender only the least amount of formatted text possible when changes/queries are made or different views of the database data are requested by the user.

It's still not fast but it's OK, changing the whole structure (AvalonEdit or `FormattedText` or `GlyphRun`) doesn't seem worth it right now, too much work, the whole serialization API with `XamlWriter.Save` and `XamlReader.Parse` simplifies much (for `FormattedText` and `GlyphRun`, I'd have to come up with a file format myself to save the formatted text to the database).

There is also the possibility of using the OpenXML SDK to create Microsoft Word .docx documents but google says rendering performance isn't great either, and I don't know if embedding an `UIElement` in the text within an `InlineUIContainer` and serializing that to be saved in the database would be possible (same problem with AvalonEdit).

Comment: How is the text generated in the first place?  Could you use a FixedDocument?

Comment: How much text are you talking about?  I've done a bunch of work with huge WPF FlowDocuments in a FlowDocumentViewer and things work pretty well.  You should probably fire up a profiler and see where you're spending your time;  Rendering text *IS* an expensive operation for WPF, but you want to make sure you're not blowing CPU computing layout due to a weird document structure or styles/colors/fonts/hyphenation/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider throwing away `RichTextBox` because it is so HUGELY SLOW (spot on). Instead of writing your own text editor check [AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx). Performance wise it beats `RichTextBox` like a baby.

Or if you need read-only text you could try a TextBlock - it supports simple formatting:

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run FontWeight="Bold">Hello</Run>
   <Run Foreground="Green">World</Run>
   <Run FontSize="24">!</Run>
</TextBlock>
```